# Scala: Is there a possibility to use terms like (x+1) as parameters for case class pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, parameter-passing, case-class

## Assume the following situation

```
case class MyCaseClass(x: Int) // some case clas with an Int parameter  

val x0 = 17 // some given Int value

val a = MyCaseClass(x=18) // a case class object

// using pattern matching to find out if *a* is of type MyCaseClass and its parameter x equals x0+1
a match {
    case MyCaseClass(x) if x == x0+1 => println("Found my case class with x==x0+1")
}
```

## Question

It would be nice if one could skip above if statement `if x == x0+1` and just write

```
case MyCaseClass(x0+1) => println("Found my case class with x==x0+1")
```

Unfortunately this does not compile - but is there some way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work if you define extractor object

```
object `+` {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(x - 1, 1)
}

a match {
  case MyCaseClass(x0 + 1) => println(x0) // 17
}
```

This will also work

```
a match {
  case MyCaseClass(x0 + _) => println(x0) // 17
}
```

and be careful, with a different value this will explode

```
a match {
  case MyCaseClass(x0 + 2) => println(x0) // MatchError
}
```

You can't restore both summands from the value of sum.

One more option is

```
object `+1` {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Int] = Some(x - 1)
}

a match {
  case MyCaseClass(`+1`(x0)) => println(x0) // 17
}
```

or

```
object `+1` {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(x - 1, 42)
}

a match {
  case MyCaseClass(x0 `+1` _) => println(x0) // 17
}
```

Honestly I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just `case MyCaseClass(18)` or if you really need to do arithmetic, you can:

```
val x1 = x0 + 1
a match {
  case MyCaseClass(`x1`) => ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this appears not any better than the if statement. I would like to have a way to use a real term(!) like x+1, not a variable, as parameter in the case class.

Comment: @FWE it is not possible. Pattern matching checks for patterns, not for terms.